# Upload a file to a website from windows forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I'm running into an error executing this code. The request does not go through when the 'Content-Type' is set to other formats

I have browsed this website and the likes of others to find a solution to this but all the examples I get lacks one thing or the other.
I therefore came up with this code which I merged from an online site but the response returned to me is just a 500: Server error.

The first code below is in my windows forms application.
Whenever I change the content type to `multipart/form-data` the request reaches the receiving end which is a website i have programmed. I put a breakpoint at the method so that i can watch the activity. But the problem here is that no file is sent to the server
Whenever i change the `Content-Type` and put `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` the request does not even go to the web server at all

This is the code in the windows form

```
private void Upload(string fileName = "2019116142944.avi")
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(UploadUrl);
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("anonymous", "password");
            request.Headers.Add("fileName", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName));
            request.ContentType = "text";//application/x-www-form-urlencoded
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0";
            request.Host = "localhost";
            request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
            request.SendChunked = true;
            request.TransferEncoding = "gzip, deflate, br";
            request.Referer = UploadUrl;
            request.Connection = "keep - alive";

            byte[] fileContent;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
            {
                fileContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }

            request.ContentLength = fileContent.Length;
            try
            {
                using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    requestStream.Write(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
                }

                using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("FileUploaded");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

and this is the code at the web server receiving end

```
public object Stream(HttpPostedFileBase videoFile)
        {
            byte[] fileContent;

            if (Request.Files.Count != 0)
            {


                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Files[0].InputStream))
                {
                    fileContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reader.ReadToEnd());
                }
                Request.Headers.GetValues("fileName").FirstOrDefault();
            var filePath = "/Uploads/files/";
            try
            {
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath(filePath) + "newfile.avi", fileContent);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string Message = ex.Message;
            }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: You have a lot of thing to revisit, here. The first, most important: you cannot send a binary file as a text file. So, not encoding. You have to read the file in binary mode and send the bytes. 2) Setting `SendChunked = true` also sets the `Transfer-Encoding` header internally, which will be `(Transfer-Encoding, chunked)`. You don't need to set the `.TransferEncoding` property and for sure not to `gzip, deflate, br` which are used to set a header to  `HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding` (as a side not `br` compression is not supported, so you cannot use it anywhere). (...)

Comment: Remove `Connection = "keep - alive";`. That's not how it's written or set and it's the default anyway. Send the file as `byte[]` using the default Stream buffer (don't set the buffer): it's optimized for Network transfer. Your IIS configuration must support `Chunked` transfer: make sure you have it enabled. There's a script that can do that, in case it's not: `adsutil.vbs`. You have to completely rewrite the server part.

Comment: I have changed to content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. whenever I put the content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` the request does not reach the server at all. (The server is also running in debug mode). But when i change it to `multipart/form-data` the request reaches the server method. Can you guess whats wrong?

Comment: With you current code, you're not sending data in a `x-www-form-urlencoded` format (you never format it that way). You *could* be sending `multipart/form-data`, (but you never defines the boundaries). Sending chunked data doesn't really agreee with the former method; in any case, you have to fix your code before anything else. A lot of code samples aroung show how to `POST` data with WebRequest. Keep in mind that, quite often, these samples are coded by devs the work on the Server side, thus related to a Server sending/receiving data to/from WebBrowsers, (...)

Comment: which must implement and understand these `POST` method. Tools like `Postman` automate the multipart data formatting, REST API handle `multipart` data (mixed-content by nature) better, because that's what they're supposed to deal with. HttpClient, for example, has it's own specific setup and tools (classes and methods) to send data in both these two formats (you should probably consider the HttpClient class, WebRequest requires a deeper understanding of the protocols involved). If you're sending raw bytes in chunked mode with your own *protocol*, consider the `application/octet-stream` format.